# Sticky nav makes header jump

Tags: jquery, nav, sticky

I am working with sticky nav and seems like when I scroll the header jumps up, and it is not smooth.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FZpf7/)

Maybe a CSS problem? or JS?

JS used:

```
var win      = $(window),
    fxel     = $('nav'),
    eloffset = fxel.offset().top;

    win.scroll(function() {
    if (eloffset < win.scrollTop()) {
        fxel.addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        fxel.removeClass("fixed");
    }
    });
```

Comment: it's the margin... but do you want the margin or not? If you keep the margin you have to set it on the `.fixed` class too.. with the disadvantage that you see your content passing on top.. (but there are also solutions for those issues :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the header is asigned the fixed position, the height of the header is gone above the rest of the elements so it jumps up to the top of the document. I changed some of your CSS, so that the header is absolute and the content has a margin from the top. See: http://jsfiddle.net/FZpf7/2/ and you will see the jumping is gone.

Changed CSS:

```
nav {
  background-color:#FBFBFB;
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
}

div.header_med { 
 margin-top:  95px;
}
```

---

Edit:
This is the second JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/FZpf7/3/

Comment: Just found the same solution few minutes ago! Thank you! Anyway I found it just adding the .fixed styles to .header class. So is right anyway?

Comment: The problem is, i didn't exactly know what you wanted to do with the sticky nav. Sometimes people want them to be fixed after scrolling a few pixels, that's why i left your code intact and tried fixing it with CSS. But to answer your question: Yes, when the navigation has to be sticky all the time you are better of setting it to fixed right away. That way, you can remove the javascript setting it to fixed during scrolling.

Comment: First of all the first solution was to make it sticky after a 20px scrolling, but found out that is going to give me more problems than solutions. And focusing on usability, both are good solutions, so i just picked the one wich is going to give me less troubles.

Comment: Well if that was your first wish (20px scrolling than sticky), you should stick(y) with that hehehe. In my answer you will find a second JSFiddle link and i altered some things so that you have to scroll 20px before getting sticky nav.

Comment: Awesome, i'll check what changes did you on the css

Comment: Back to work @veritas87 I tried to work on your solution, but I can't make it work on my website, so after a break, I found the "fixed nav" solution (without the sticky after scroll) could improve more my usability. What do you think about it? Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the margin / padding on both `html` and `body`, and remove the `margin-top` of `#container` :

```
body, html{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#container {
  /*margin-top:10px;*/
}
```

Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FZpf7/1/), I might have misunderstood your problem!